# how do i vertically center two elements in a parent?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

As you can see in the demo, once I add the `<em>` the `<button>` is displaced.

I would like the `button` to be vertically center in the `footer`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/chovy/5h5hc/1/

**HTML**

```
<footer>
    <button class="btn-primary">Reply</button>
</footer>

<footer>
    <em></em>
    <button class="btn-primary">Reply</button>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
footer {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

em {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a small change to your HTML.

```
<footer>
    <button class="btn-primary">Reply</button>
</footer>

<footer>
    <em>&nbsp;</em>
    <button class="btn-primary">Reply</button>
</footer>
```

Add some text to your `<em>` it works as expected. (If you don't want any text in there, just put `&nbsp;` for a space.)

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/5h5hc/3/)

Comment: you add just space. but in your demo reply button not get vertical-align

Comment: works for me. thanks. I wonder if there is a way to add the space with css. I don't like having to remember to put `&nbsp;` in there.

Answer (score 0):

LIke this please add `float:left;` in `em` selector

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5h5hc/2/)**

**CSS**

```
em {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Float left will move the box from right position to left, we should not try to push an element to the other side.

Comment: I don't want it floated left though. and your demo was my original.

Comment: @SUNNY R GUPTA you check my demo why you get me negative point

Comment: I saw your DEMO, basically it has a glitch, you modified the layout of the original code.

Comment: @chovy http://jsfiddle.net/5h5hc/2/ see this demo and just add float:left; in your em selector may i sure you get result.

Comment: I don't want it left aligned.

Answer (score 0):

You could tell them to behave like tables: http://jsfiddle.net/5h5hc/12/. Then your footer can be as flexible as you like and the content will always be horizontally centered.

```
<footer>
    <div><em>an em</em><button class="btn-primary">Reply</button></div>
</footer>
```

css:

```
footer {
    display:table;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid #990000;
    width:100%;
}
footer div {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply add `vertical-align: top` to the `<em>` to negate the default behaviour of the `display: inline-block` declaration. 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5h5hc/13/)